# Using javascript variable defined in previously loaded dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I have a container page with a few lines of script containing the following line:

```
var connection = $.connection.hub.start();
```

And I have multiple parts loading dynamically in my container page. How can I use the `connection` variable in the dynamically loaded partial views. eg:

```
connection
    .pipe(init)
    .done(function () {
        console.log("hey");
    });
```

The above code piece in my dynamically loaded view says:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: connection is not defined`

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Just make sure `var connection` is in a variable scope accessible to the code that needs to use it. Functions create variable scope. Code inside a function can see the variables outside it, but outer code can't see variables declared inside nested functions.

Comment: ...though I don't know what you mean by "previously loaded DOM element".

Comment: I mean I'm loading a page and after that I'm updating some parts of it dynamically. After the word you mentioned in your first conmment 'scope', I googled how to define 'global variables' in js and find out that I have to define it as 'window.connection'. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so we aid in understanding, if you define store it into `window.connection` that is implicitly creating a member variable of the window object in javacript.

Javascript allows you to create functions and member variables 'on the fly' which is powerful but can easily be abused. I personally try to create a few global objects separated by purpose declared in the global namespace.

You can do the same (if you use jquery) by:

```
$().ready(function() {
   var g_someGlobalState = true;
   var g_someGlobalCounter = 0;
   // etc.
});
```

I would consider this generally bad practice as these declarations become global for ALL javascript libraries and you may have naming collisions. It is generally better to apply a custom namespace to your code to ensure no conflicts happen down the road.

I do this with a helper namespace function in jquery that I got from the following location:
http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/26/basic-javascript-part-8-namespaces/

```
$().ready(function() {

  function namespace(namespaceString) {
    var parts = namespaceString.split('.'),
      parent = window,
      currentPart = '';

    for (var i = 0, length = parts.length; i < length; i++) {
      currentPart = parts[i];
      parent[currentPart] = parent[currentPart] || {};
      parent = parent[currentPart];
    }

    return parent;
  }

  // Declare global storage
  var MyAppName_GlobalSettings = namespace('MyAppName.Settings');

  // Assign variables
  MyAppName_GlobalSettings.connection = $.connection.hub.start();

});
```

Now, within this javascript page, whenever you want to access this connection, you can simply reference `MyAppName_GlobalSettings.connection`